# How do I include greek symbols in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, greek

I can't seem to insert Greek symbols in my beamer presentation. This is how the top section looks like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newcommand{\exinline}[1]{(\refstepcounter{theorem}Exercise~\thetheorem\label{#1})}
\usepackage{listings}%% to include code
\lstset{
    language=Java, basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\footnotesize\color{blue}\ttfamily,
 }

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}
\begin{document}
%here is a sample page
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Trial insert Greek Symbols}
     \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> \epsilon
        \item<2> Some text
     \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Whenever I remove the \epsilon, my file compiles without error. When I add the \epsilon it produces this error 
`"!Missing $ inserted. ,inserted text> $ \end{frame}"`
Also is there any specific arrangements when including a package in the latex file (E.g. A certain package should be above some other package while including in a file).

Regards

Comment: `\epsilon` should be used in math mode, you have to write `$\epsilon$`.

Comment: Some packages have to be loaded after other packages, the mots notable being `hyperref` , which has to loaded at the end (with some exceptions — mainly cleveref).

Answer (score 2):

Either you put your `\epsilon` in math mode (`$\epsilon$`) or you use a package such as `textgreek` and its `\textepsilon`.

(Last option would be using a unicode-capable engine like Xe/LuaLaTeX and inserting the unicode character).